# PHP does not save data in a modal

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have made a modal on my website that collects 5 data from a modal form, but when I click the button to perform the action and redirect me to the page where I work with the data that was set, they tell me that they are undefined , they have not been saved, here I show the error:
Code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editar-<?php echo $customer['id'];?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Actualizar producto</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="form" action="logic/actualizarcolumna.php?editar=<?php echo $customer['id'];?>" method="POST">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label"><b>Nombre del producto</b></label>
                        <input type="text" name="nombreproducto1" class="form-control" id="nombreproducto1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Precio de compra" class="col-form-label"><b>Precio de compra</b></label>
                        <input type="text" name="preciocompra1" class="form-control" id="preciocompra1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="asddsa" class="col-form-label"><b>Precio de venta</b></label>
                        <input type="text" name="precioventa1" class="form-control" id="precioventa1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="address"><b>Link del producto <a href="https://tinyurl.com/" target="_blank">(Acortar link)</a></b></label>
                        <textarea name="linkproducto1" placeholder="Link del producto" class="form-control" id="linkproducto1"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="seccion" class="col-form-label"><b>Sección del producto</b></label>
                        <input type="text" name="seccionproducto1" class="form-control" id="seccionproducto1">
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                <a href="logic/actualizarcolumna.php?editar=<?php echo $customer['id'];?>">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar cambios</button>
                </a>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

PICTURES:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rw7up.png)

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9BSz.png)

Comment: None of your form elements have a value tag

Comment: Added value and same error

Comment: Sorry, I was skimming through. You dont have a submit button either.

Comment: Added and not work